# some issues concerning the aspx file in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, indentation

Q:

I want to ask two questions concerning the `visual studio`.

1- is there a way to indent the `aspx` file , because most of the time , this file is so long and not tidy ,make me feel noisy and take a lot of time to modify the tags . i wanna to know if there is some trick in visual studio to indent the file like the  `.cs` file when removing the last curly brace and type it again the code turned to be readable and indented.

2- some times when i select a specific control in the design view and go to the source view, the visual studio behave in a strange manner and i find all the source is selected. what is the problem here.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you mean formatting  **GOTO** Edit --> Advanced and play around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format the document you can use:

Ctrl+E, D - format document

or Edit > Advanced > Format Document

This will apply default indenting to your whole document